# как заставить не растягиваться картинки в спрайте для sf::RectangleShape

Tags: c++, sfml

необходимо рисовать пунктирные отрезки , а так же отрезки типа "точка-тире-точка" разной длины. sfml рисовать отрезки по-моему не умеет, а тем более пунктиры . поэтому я рисую при помощи sf::RectangleShape и текстуры. В текстуру я подгружаю картинку отрисованную в паинте заранее.  Длина прямоугольника как известно регулируется первым параметром  : setSize(sf::Vector2f(50, 5)); и тут как раз прилетает проблема: мне необходимо чтобы картинка не искажалась при изменении этого параметра, нужно чтобы картинка или тупо обрубалась, если не помещается, либо если наоборот приресовывалась другая такая же и так далее по всей длине, в конечном итоге обрубаясь на конце или нет. а происходит растяжка картинки. можете что-нибудь посоветовать ?

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
 
using namespace sf;
 
int main()
{
  RenderWindow window(VideoMode(1500, 1000), "SFML Works!");
  sf::Texture sTest;
    sTest.loadFromFile("pica/line1.png"); //картинку в паинте нарисовал во такую: - - - - 
  sf::RectangleShape line_with_thickness;
   line_with_thickness.setTexture(&sTest);
   line_with_thickness.setSize(sf::Vector2f(50, 5));

  while (window.isOpen())
  {
    Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
      if (event.type == Event::Closed)
        window.close();
    }
    window.clear(Color::White);
     window.draw(line_with_thickness);
     window.display();
  }
 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Зачем вам этот RectangleShape? Обрабатывайте в пиксельном шейдере uv текстуры в экранной системе координат с настройкой семплера на зацикливание (wrap).

Comment: @user7860670 это что такое вообще ? это вообще SFML ?

Comment: SFML - это адаптер для пачки мультимедийных API, рисование в нем происходит посредством opengl.

Comment: @user7860670 вы метод предложили , это вообще из области sfml или это из области низкоуровневой API  ?

Comment: Это из области высокоуровнего api opengl. sfml сам по себе мало что умеет, это просто адаптер упрощающий работу.

Comment: @user7860670 всё проще гораздо

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Извините конечно, я не доконца понял что вы хотите, но `sfml` может рисовать фигуры, а пунктирная линия это и есть прямоугольник. Вот сылка где где подробно раскапзанно как создать простые геометрические фигуры  [про SFML](https://ravesli.com/graficheskaya-biblioteka-sfml-sozdanie-prostyh-geometricheskih-figur/)

Comment: ок. как бы вы нарисовали бы вот такой отрезок  - - - - - - - - - ? или такой _ . _ .

Comment: @АндрейГуренков `// Линия с заданной толщиной
  RectangleShape line_1(Vector2f(130.f, 5.f));` Просто повторить нужное количество раз, так же можно между линиями делать по этому подобию и тире с точкой

Comment: вы представляете сколько это объектов будет в результате ? )))

Comment: @АндрейГуренков можно сделать 2 класа, один с пунктиром, второй с пункитр + точка, а при обьявлении этого обьекта передавать длину линии в пикселях или в количестве обьектов...

Comment: да, может быть отказаться от рисунков вообще, а указать только толщину окантовки и использовать массив Vertex .

Comment: всё вышло одним прямоугольником и одним рисунком.